# Can't set default value with hook_field_widget_form_alter()

Tags: forms

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context){
if ($context['field']['type'] == 'node_reference' &&
  empty($element['#default_value'])) {
$element['#default_value'] = 51113;
  }
}
```

the above does not work - I'm simply trying to set a default value through hook_field_widget_form_alter. The hook works - I can alter options and so forth, but not the default value. Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to change the default value in the widget form instead of the form (form_alter)? Maybe this thread can help you https://api.drupal.org/comment/52558#comment-52558

Comment: I tried it both ways with the same result :-/ I found a thread on drupal.org recommending hook_field_widget_form_alter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved - I noticed my default values worked on node-edit forms, so I tried raising my custom module's weight, which seemed to do the trick :-)